# Symfony 4. How do I extend the DateType to be HiddenType insted

Tags: symfony

I have created a data transformation string to date, but I really wanted to try and extend the DateType as it has all the logic for handling dates, has anyone done this before or should I just use a DataTransformer (which is what I have implemented)?

I tried doing the following:

```php
Class HiddenDateType extends DateType {
   public function getParent() {
       return HiddenType::class;
   } 

}
```

But this didn't work, when I looked into the DateType Class it was a little more complicated than I was expecting and didn't know where to hook into the returned type.

I found a few solutions but most of them where pretty hacky, ie; Hiding the entire field via CSS, or changing the type inside the twig template.

This is my transformer, it's VERY redemantry, its frustrating that there is code RIGHT inside the DateType but my skills are lacking :(

```
class StringToDateTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{

    /**
     * @param \DateTime|null $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($value)
    {
        if(null === $value) {
            return '';
        }

        return $value->format('Y-m-d');
    }


    /**
     * @param  string $value
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        try {
            return new \DateTime($value);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                'Invalid Format for %s format yyyy-mm-dd',
                $value
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

On the actual rendered page there is a single div which has a `daterangepicker` javascript event (on click) is attached to it, this event is triggered when clicked which allows the user to select a start and end date.

The javascript will then populate two hidden DateType fields (startDate, endDate) within the form.

This is the div that the `daterangepicker` picker is attached to.

```html
<div id="selectedRange">
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
<span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
 </div>
```

Comment: Do you want hide  DateType class as like HiddenType?

Comment: I wanted to Hide the DateType because I have a Div box with a date range picker attached to it, I don't want users to type in dates, I would rather restrict the date range format to something that can easily be processed (yyyy-mm-dd),  then try and process the multiple ways a user can enter the date range.  So the field itself will be hidden, but the data is two separate hidden DateType's that hold start and end date.  If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in your formType class `buildForm()` method

```
// ./src/form/yourType.php

$builder->add('hidden_date_field_name', DateType::class, [
  'attr' => [
    'hidden' => 'hidden',
    'disabled' => 'disabled',
  ],
]);
```

Comment: This will print out the entire row, which includes markup that doesn't really need to be on the page.  I could of course just use the `{{ form_widget(formName.startdate}}`  hence why I was trying to use a transformer or better still use the DateType and extend it to create a hidden input field.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine using a **DateType** or **DateTimeType** if you do not plan to use something like bootstrap timepicker or any other JS modification of your input.

However, if that's the case and you want to make a better looking date input, the simple way to do it is to use it as a string like so :

```
$builder->add('date', TextType::class, array(
                        'required' => true,
                        'label'=>'Date',
                        'attr' => array(
                            'class'   => 'datetimepicker',
                            'data-provide' => 'datepicker',
                            'data-format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:ii'
                        ),
                    ));
```

And be sure to add your ModelTransformer to the input in your FormType like so:

```
$builder->get('date')
                    ->addModelTransformer(new StringToDateTransformer());
```

Note that you can specify the date format for your js component in the input attribute.

Comment: I have attached the datetimepicker directly to the id of the Div, I should have specified that there are two "hidden" DateType fields that get populated by some JavaScript, my bad.